# first middle last name is in cell A, next sheet having one name tried text left formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

In cell A first name middle name last name in one cell & i have another list in sheet 2 have only one name. It may be first middle last name is it possible through look up to get data. If data matching it has to provide as in cell A first middle last names to my sheet2 look-up data.

I have tried multiple text find formula. Is this possible in Excel please advise or do I need to go macro code for this ?

Much appreciated for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please provide example data so we can see what you have and what you're trying to do.  Also check out the [tour] as well as [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: +1 @ashleedawg data is needed. Basavaraj: you can possibly use a LOOKUP/SEARCH based construct but if there are duplicates (as they are names) then it will give you hard time.

Comment: sheet 1 column A have first middle last name and sheet 2 I have names which is only one part of column A ( like first name or middle or last name). I cant split names in sheet 1 because have reports and other formulas ( If I split I need to write 3 times V lookup formula)

Comment: Any suggestions how to get data

Answer (score 1):

Split the names in column A into three columns using the Data,TextToColumns feature, then use three MATCH formulas (one on each column) to find the cell and then use INDEX to return the contents of Column A

=MATCH(sheet2!name you are looking for,sheet1!columnB,0) will return either #N/A or the number of the cell in column B if it finds a match. INDEX(sheet1!A:A,x,0)  will return the contents of the cell which is at row x in column A. So

INDEX(sheet1!A:A,MATCH(Sheet2!name,sheet1!B:B,0),0)

will give you the full name from column A if the first name is in column B or an error. Repeat for columns C and D

Comment: I got your point , am really not sure here Index formula works ? I have never formulated INDEX formula please help